# angular $stateProvider not routing as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

In my main `index.html` file I have the following simple markup...

```
<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <div ui-view></div>
</body>
```

In my `app.js` I am using `$stateProvider` to create routes so I can display certain pages...

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app');
  $stateProvider

    .state('app', {
      url: '/app',
      templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
      controller: 'AppCtrl'
    })
    .state('app.accounts', {
      url: '/accounts',
      templateUrl: 'templates/accounts.html'
    })
});
```

When the page loads, the first state is loaded, meaning I can see the contents of `menu.html` in my main `index.html` and the controller `AppCtrl` is passed to this state.

My `AppCtrl` loads an API that I am using on click of a button from `menu.html`, the API provides a UI for a user to login, and once the credentials are good, the `success` is called...

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout, $state) {

  $scope.create = function() {
      var linkHandler = Plaid.create({
        env: 'tartan',
        clientName: 'Example Project',
        key: 'test_key',
        product: 'connect',
        onSuccess: function(token) {
            $state.go('app.accounts');
        },
    });

    linkHandler.open();
  }   
});
```

What the API does is pretty irrelevant, but as you can see, I am passing `$state.go('app.accounts');` on success. But instead of changing the state to `app.accounts`, I believe the `otherwise` statement is called because all I see is the contents of the `app` state.

Why is this so? I've been stuck on this issue for some time now.

Comment: Can you make sure that "onSuccess" callback has access to $state. You can console.log($state); inside onSuccess function.

Comment: @RaviTeja it seems that it does have access. When I `console.log` I get something like `Object {params: Object, current: Object, $current: extend, transition: null}`

Comment: Do you have a controller associated with `app.accounts` state?

Comment: @RaviTeja No i do not, should I?

Comment: @RaviTeja actually hold on, maybe I do. I put the `ng-controller` in my `body` tag...Could this be the cause?

Comment: I believe you should define a controller for child state as well. And try removing ng-controller from body.

Comment: @RaviTeja ok so I did both those things and I still get the same issue. It never goes to the new state. I made an empty controller for `app.accounts`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`app.accounts` is a child state of `app`. That means in `menu.html` there must be `<ui-view>` in order to display `accounts.html`.

If you don't want to display `accounts.html` inside `menu.html`, you shouldn't make `accounts` a child state of `app`:

```
<body ng-app="starter">
    <div ui-view></div>
</body>
```

and

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app');
  $stateProvider

    .state('app', {
      url: '/app',
      templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
      controller: 'AppCtrl'
    })
    .state('accounts', {
      url: '/accounts',
      templateUrl: 'templates/accounts.html'
    })
});
```